# Reusing input variable in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is it okay to use the same input variable when using multiple LINQ operators.

For example:

```
list.Where(o => o.Name == "John").Average(o => o.Age);
```

Note, the use of `o` twice in the above code.

Comment: Yes.  Each is a separate expression.

Comment: yes it is. They are in different scope

Comment: Of course each is separate.

Comment: @Sandy, in the future, try testing small snippets of code in LinqPad or some other tool. [Here's an example](http://csharppad.com/gist/7760919f83da4b18458a).

Comment: Mike, why do you assume I have not tested this myself? It takes longer to login, ask the question, vote for the answer, etc. than to do a test in VS. Just because it works for me in my limited test does not mean it correct usage or best practice. And I did not expect that I would have to justify getting help from my peers.

Comment: Why this question was downvoted? Is there any reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a small example:

```
class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<TestClass>
            {
                new TestClass("Name1", 10, new[] {40,50}), new TestClass("Name2", 20, new[] {60,70}), new TestClass("Name3", 30, new[] {80,90}), new TestClass("Name4", 40, new[] {70,20}),
                new TestClass("Name5", 50, new[] {50,40}),new TestClass("Name6", 60, new[] {20,50}),new TestClass("John", 70, new[] {10,20}),new TestClass("John", 80, new[] {40,70})
            };

            var data = list.Where(o => o.Name == "John").Average(o/*Correct Use*/ => o.Age);
            var otherData = list.Where(o => o.Name == "John" && o.Marks.Average(o/*InCorrect use*/ => o) > 35).Average(o/*Correct Use*/ => o.Age);
            Console.WriteLine("data : {0}", data);
            Console.WriteLine("otherData : {0}", otherData);
        }
    }

    class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass(string name, int age, IEnumerable<int> marks)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
            Marks = marks.ToArray();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int[] Marks { get; set; }
    }
```

You can use same variable in two different expressions but if you use same variable in nested expressions you will get compile error.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above, this might be helpful in better visualizing the scope of your queries...

[image: Example]

Each box represents a scope, if you had something like

```
var o = new Foo();
list.Where(o => o.Name == "Jhon").Average(o => o.Age);
```

Then you would have a problem as the variable `o` has already been assigned to an instance of `Foo`.

[image: Example 2]